# Automate Seedbox Downloads to Linux Box

Tags: download, automation, download-manager

I currently have a seedbox overseas (using rutorrent), which has RSS setup to automatically download TV shows from a private tracker.

I want to setup an automated downloader from the Seedbox to my Linux server (which has XBMC on it). Once a torrent is finished on the Seedbox, the automated downloader will download the completed file. Wishlist: Rename file, add nfo details / wallpapers etc and then trigger XBMC to update.

Are there any solutions out there at the moment? Or do I need to write a custom set of scripts?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look a the source of the [rutorrent Unpack plugin](http://code.google.com/p/rutorrent/wiki/PluginUnpack) and see how it determines that a file is complete. You could use that API write your own plugin to automate a file transfer.

I've looked through the source and the [plugins](http://rutorrent.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/unpack/) seems to have a standard mechanism